# Azure SQL Backups for IaaS

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have a SQL Server within the organisation I work for that is on an Azure VM, and I see in the Error Log backups like this this are being generated.

It's an actual VM with SQL Server installed on it. How would these backups be getting generated?

```
Date  8/15/2018 4:59:50 PM
Log  SQL Server (Current - 8/15/2018 4:13:00 PM)
Source  Backup
Message
Database backed up. Database: AB_Train_2015, creation date(time): 2017/11/15(14:13:46), pages dumped: 113195, first LSN: 102198:63336:37, last LSN: 102198:63368:1, number of dump devices: 1, device information: (FILE=1, TYPE=URL: {'https://wchstandardstorage.blob.core.windows.net/backupcontainer/AB_Train_2015_5c4eeb6d0ed14cd2bfef9315fa6beb26_20180815165905+10.bak'}). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Some support automatic backups to blobs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-automated-backup-v2 Did this VM materialise out of nowhere? Who provisioned it?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - SQL Server 2017. I've only just started, so no idea, and there's no documentation or any details as to what the backup strategy is.

Comment: Well based on the link I posted, I guess whoever provisioned the machine enabled _Automated Backup v2 for Azure Virtual Machines_